# Android SDK Path using Ionic

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, ionic-framework, cross-platform

Every time i run my Ionic project got the following error [my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsVXP.png)

Not that my android sdk path is : "C:\Android\sdk" not the path giving in the error
Where can i change the existed sdk path in the error image to "C:\Android\sdk"
any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my move all SDK files to the the path in the error image it worked very well